# cataloginventory_stock_status entry issue Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.2.5, cataloginventory, manage-stock

I did not get an entry in `cataloginventory_stock_status` table after indexing.
Product stock entry is exist in `cataloginventory_stock_item` table.
I have checked this thing in Magento 2.2.5 in default version and that things working fine.
I did not know where I made mistake.
I think I have made mistake in any configuration setting.
Please suggest me in which configuration setting I made mistake and I disabled **Manage Stock**. When I check in Magento I found below query during indexing.

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cis`.`website_id`, `cis`.`stock_id`, IF(cisi.qty > 0, cisi.qty, 0) AS `qty`, IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 1, MAX(cisi.is_in_stock), 1) AS `status` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis` INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = e.entity_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `mcpei` ON e.entity_id = mcpei.entity_id AND mcpei.attribute_id = 97 AND mcpei.value = 1 WHERE (cis.website_id = 0) AND (e.type_id = 'simple') AND (e.entity_id IN(21801, 21802, 21803, 21804, 21805, 21806, 21807, 22000)) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id`, `cis`.`website_id`,`cis`.`stock_id`.
```

This query result added in `cataloginventory_stock_status` table but this query returns no result. You can review that select query in `<root>/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/ResourceModel/Indexer/Stock/DefaultStock.php` line number `225`

Answer (score 5):

I got an issue. I found `website_id` = 1 instead of 0 in `cataloginventory_stock` table. I change website id to 0.

Comment: I don't know how, but it works. Finally I got it

Comment: You really saved the day, I was debugging 2 days  a magento 2 upgraded from 2.1  - 2.3 and for some reason the cataloginventory_stock_status table was empty after the upgrade and with reindex it wasnt updating.  The problem we had was, the category page wasnt showing products , the collection was always 0.  Thanks again.